# Free abelian groups and free groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-groups, free-abelian-group

So I learned about both free groups and free abelian groups, their constructions, universal properties etc. It seems that they are completely different concepts, even though they are both free objects in their respective categories. I am still a bit confused about the following: if we start with a free group and adjoin commutative relations between their generators, do we get a free abelian group? In other words, is
$$ \langle F(a_1, \dots, a_n) \mid a_ia_j=a_ja_i \text{ for } 1 \leq i,j, \leq n \rangle = \mathbb{Z}^{(a_1, \dots, a_n)}$$
true? Are there some examples that will help clear up my confusion? Thanks.

Comment: I think for the relations you mean: $a_ia_ja_i^{-1}a_j^{-1}$.

Comment: @Nick You are right, I just edited it.

Comment: To answer your question: yes. See the wikipedia page for "free abelian group" under the heading "presentation". It addresses this.

Comment: Yes, the abelianization of a free group is a free abelian group.

Comment: I guess that should have been obvious. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I think that the formal way to go towards this is looking at the quotient of the free group by the normal subgroup generated by all those relations (this is basically the definition you wrote). so we have that every element in the quotient is a product of the images of the generators, and you can easily bring that to the form of an abelian word. you can also prove easily that this is indeed free, and by the same number of generators